# How to create markdown editor

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, markdown

I'm in the process of creating my markdown editor for a web application. A better analogy of this could be Stack Overflow/[RedNotebook](http://rednotebook.sourceforge.net/), where when we type our content into the textbox, the immediate formatted output is shown next to it.

Are there any example implementations of such a model? Or should I start coding from scratch, starting by creating a textbox etc?

Any open source API's for this?

Comment: This is not the proper place for this question. This sort of question is better suited for [chat]. See [about StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/about).

Comment: https://github.com/evilstreak/markdown-js

Comment: See [What is a good client side markdown editor?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2357022/what-is-a-good-client-side-markdown-editor) for options, including the editor used on this site.

Answer (score 3):

I have the perfect solution for you, I just wrote this.

Download [PHP Markdown Extra](http://michelf.ca/projects/php-markdown/), and put in the same dir as this script:

```
<?php

include_once("markdown.php");

if(isset($_GET['mode']) && $_GET['mode'] == 'ajax')
    die(Markdown($_POST['markdown']));

?><html>
    <head>
        <style>
             span     { text-align: left; width: 49% }
             textarea { height: 100%; width: 100% }
            #left     { float: left; }
            #right    { float: right; }
        </style>
        <script type='text/javascript'>
            function ajax()
            {
                if(window.XMLHttpRequest)
                    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
                else if(window.ActiveXObject)
                    var request = ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");

                request.open("POST", "?mode=ajax", true);
                request.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                request.send('markdown=' + document.getElementById('markdown').value);

                request.onreadystatechange = function()
                {
                    if(request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200)
                        document.getElementById('right').innerHTML = request.responseText;
                }
            }

            window.onload = function(){ ajax(); }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <span id='left'>
                <textarea id='markdown' onkeyup='ajax();'></textarea>
            </span>
            <span id='right'>
                Loading...
            </span>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

[image: db-ajax]

Of course this is just a simple concept. It needs some improvement, but it's the basis of what you're looking for I think.

Comment: You should probably throttle those AJAX requests...otherwise it's going to create heavy traffic on the server...plus the requests aren't guaranteed to come back in a particular order, so you could end up with your preview window out of sync with the user's input.

Comment: @TimMedora As I say, it's just a basis to go off. Ideally, I'd write a full-blown JS solution, but this was something I just happened to have recently made, and that seemed quite fitting. I wouldn't recommend sending thousands of HTTP requests long-term though.

Comment: @TimMedora I've posted a better answer.

Answer (score 3):

[Pagedown](http://pagedown.googlecode.com/hg/demo/browser/demo.html) is a better answer.

It's what Stack Exchange's editor [runs off](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10369/which-tools-and-technologies-are-used-to-build-the-stack-exchange-network).

[image]